# How to reuse the Eclipse 4 IDE Perspective Features in an RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-juno, e4

is there an easy way to reuse the complete Perspective implementation from the Eclipse Juno 4.2 IDE ("Open Perspective", Customize Perspective, "Save Perspective As ...", "Reset Perspective...", "Close Perspective...", ... ) in an e4 RCP application (if possible without using the Eclipse 3 compatibility layer)?

Thanks and Best Regards
Marc

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean to reuse them as Menu items, just as they are in Eclipse.

You can locate their ids using the Plugin Spy - on your Eclipse development platform, press `Alt++Shift+F2` and then click on the Window menu and then on Customize Perspective... (for example). This will give you its id as `org.eclipse.ui.window.customizePerspective`.

Then go to your `plugin.xml` and to the menu extension where you want to add this command, right click and add a command. For the `commandId` you put that id you found (`org.eclipse.ui.window.customizePerspective`). You can even find these ids when you click on `Browse`, next to `commandId`.

Unfortunately for E4 RCP you must use plugin.xml for the Eclipse defined commands. If you do not wish to, then you can get an idea of the implementation of the command by viewing its source code.

I have a more detailed answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370898/462285